# Mouse stops working in Bootcamp (XP)

Tags: bootcamp, mouse, windows

I've been using Bootcamp (XP) with no problem for quite a while now. Today, when I tried booting to XP, my mouse will work for about a second and then stop working. If i unplug/replug it, it will sometimes work for another second and then stop. The keyboard works fine. I've tried several different mice, all corded.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on or how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using other mice, either the same make and model or another brand altogether, and do they exhibit the same problem? If not, then you probably have a hardware failure with your mouse.

Beyond that, what have you changed or upgraded or installed on the Mac side just before this problem appeared? What have you changed or upgraded or installed on the Windows XP side just before the problem appeared? There must be something. This is the key to troubleshooting.

[Reset the PRAM](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1379).

If that does not help, report back.

Comment: I've tried several different mice, of different make/model. None of them work in XP, but they all work in OS X. Tried resetting the PRAM, but it didn't seem to do anything. When I plug in the mouse under windows, the device manager seems to notice that I plugged in a mouse and lists it as 'apple optical mouse' as usual. I haven't installed anything on the Mac or Windows side since I used the computer last, but I am happy to supply any logs if there is something you suspect may be the problem.

Comment: Are you sure that you haven't installed any Apple firmware updates or other Apple system updates recently? You haven't migrated to Lion, have you? Based on what you've reported, I would concentrate on the Windows XP side: what could have changed within Windows XP in software, and how to repair it.

Comment: I haven't upgraded to Lion, still on Snow Leopard. When I left work on Thursday, things were working fine. There's an off-chance that a sysadmin could have come by and installed something, but unlikely...